# issues in ORACLE DB connection

Tags: java, database, eclipse, oracle, driver

help me please! I've looked at other topics but I haven't found the solution.
I must do a DBconnection class in JAVA using eclipse.
This is my code

```
public static void main(String[] argv) { 
    try {

        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }

    Connection connection = null;
    try {

        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE", "username",
                "password");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }
```

if i run returns the error:

java.lang.ClassNot    FoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver

I know it's a common mistake but I can not find the solution.
In the project I imported the jar file ojdbc6.jar for drivers. I do not understand why it doesn't works.

Comment: ojdbc6.jar isn't there in the classpath.

Comment: Try to look for how to add to your java build path your ojdbc6.jar in google accoording the ide you are using, if you do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the `ojdbc6.jar` in classpath.

You can add into classpath as below

You can get the jar from `{ORACLE DRIVER INSTALL PATH}\jdbc\lib\ojdbc6.jar`

Then,

```
Go to Project properties (Project -> Properties) -> Java Build Path -> 
Libraries -> Add external JARs -> 
select ojdbc6.jar from your filesystem
```

As the name suggests `ClassNotFoundException` in Java is a subclass of `java.lang.Exception` and Comes when **Java Virtual Machine** tries to load a particular class and **doesn't found the requested class in classpath.**

Another important point about this Exception is that, It is a **checked Exception** and you need to provide explicitly Exception handling while using methods which can possibly throw `ClassNotFoundException` in java either by using try-catch block or by using throws clause.

[Oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassNotFoundException.html)

```
public class ClassNotFoundException
 extends ReflectiveOperationException
```

Thrown when an application tries to load in a class through its string name using:

- The forName method in class Class.
- The findSystemClass method in class ClassLoader .
- The loadClass method in class ClassLoader.

but no definition for the class with the specified name could be found.

**Links**

- [Add-JARs-to-Project](http://www.wikihow.com/Add-JARs-to-Project-Build-Paths-in-Eclipse-%28Java%29)

Comment: I don't know. JAR file is already present

I send u screenshot if u want. In project->properties->JAVAbuiltpath there is the JAR.

Answer (score 0):

Add oracle driver(.jar) file onto classpath.

Please refer to below link for driver download.
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/index-091264.html

Answer (score 0):

You may have added the JDBC driver JAR to the build path but not to the runtime classpath. That's why when running your app the classes can't be found. You need to edit the Launch Configuration for your app and make sure the JDBC driver JAR is included on it's classpath.

Here's how you can open the dialog to edit launch (run or debug) configurations:
[image: Screen shot]